# Dataset - Vehicle make/model/year (free)

Tags: database

I am creating an app that needs all available US automotive make/models for each year. I have read several suggestions on other posts, like use Freebase or DbPedia or EPA, but those datasets all appear rather incomplete and inconsistent. I checked out open APIs like Edmond's, but they restrict storing their data - I need it in my db, so that doesn't work. Any suggestions where I can get this data without having to shell out money?

Comment: Now who would go to all the effort of creating and updating that much data, and then give it away?

Comment: How does anything open-sourced get started ;)

Comment: Not seeing a vehicle database as the sort of thing a free software boyo would want to spend a few years on, myself

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, who would go to all that effort and give the data away?  The U.S. Government, that's who! In truth they're not giving it away as it's been paid for by our tax dollars...well, mine anyway.  It occurred to me that the EPA tracks fuel economy and thus must have information on all vehicles sold in the U.S.  Their data has make and model (by engine and transmission) but not trim lines. So, for example, the data contains 4 entries for the 2011 Kia Soul as there were 2 engines and 2 transmissions offered that year.  http://www.epa.gov/otaq/fedata.htm

Comment: @Paul, Not exactly what I meant was it? What commercial organisation would do it? Governments don't count they don't have to not make losses, never mind profits.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Sorry for not reading your mind :)  The point is the data desired by the OP exists and is free, not who created it and why.

Comment: We've decided to do it.  Granted it is UK only at the moment but you are free, without restriction, to do what you like with it:  http://www.keeresources.co.uk/data/free-vehicle-data/

Comment: The problem is not offering a free database, the problem is that it has to be continually updated to be relevant.

Comment: We update daily with every vehicle released in the UK!

Comment: Some newer answers here http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7577/1511

Comment: I’ve been looking for a DB for the longest time, it never made sense to me why a free one wasn’t available somewhere. I then discovered that the US government provides one for free here: Fuel Economy Web Services (https://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/ws/index.shtml).
Hopefully that’ll help people find the right place, as opposed to clicking on advertisements…

Comment: Does not contain Year info yet. Maybe someone will contribute or if I get time to add it I will https://github.com/snowballrandom/vehicle-make-model-data

Comment: https://github.com/abhionlyone/us-car-models-data

Comment: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Apparently there is not much out there. And a lot of doubt that someone would be willing to provide such a repository. So I solved the problem myself, and am sharing my dataset with anyone else who finds themselves facing the same problem.

https://github.com/n8barr/automotive-model-year-data

Comment: I pulled this down and plan to update it for 2014/2015.  Unless someone else already has done that?  Will issue a pull request when I do.

Comment: I was searching for a database that had curb weight and other model specifics. I found that for just over a hundred dollars, you can get the best list available free and paid alike from http://www.mssql-vehicle-data.com/

Comment: @Cyberdrew the problem with Edmunds is that their TOS clearly states you cannot permanently store the data.

Comment: Since this hasn't been updated in 2 years, does anyone have an updated database script?

Comment: The NHTSA have a free database: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getallmanufacturers?page=1

Comment: As mentioned by @Dai, the NHTSA is going to be the most reliable source of vehicle information. Its maintained by the US Government for safety and traffic purposes. It is relied on for government highway and law enforcement services, and the database is maintained with your (American citizen) tax dollars. So it is free with no limits, and maintained regularly. Information is actually provided by manufacturers. The github link above is basically worthless. Not mentioned and only contains, year, maker, and model data. It is far from complete.

Comment: This would be the best for what I need too bad is not kept up to date..

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question. But please do check/contribute to my repo https://github.com/abhionlyone/usa-car-models-data

Comment: I has been looking for similar car database and I came across this question and tried few websites including CarQueryAPI where I found numerous missing cars and errors so I had to ask for a refund. I was the happiest man when I found https://www.teoalida.com/cardatabase/ it does have many databases to choose from, some are cheap and some are really expensive but I contacted site owner via live chat and he prepared for me a custom list with only 2010-2019 models at lower price than what I would had to pay for full database 1990-2019. It worth my money, database being complete and very accurate.

Comment: your download is unfortunately out of date, but thank you

Comment: Cannot recommend @Dai 's comment enough!  The NHTSA's API is free, fast, open, and always up to date: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/

Comment: NHTSA only USA vehicles though...

Comment: Does anyone know if NHTSA API provides an option to sort data? I couldn't find anything on the documentation. I'm asking this before I start to do it on my side after fetching.

Answer (score 18):

These guys have an API that will give the results.  It's also free to use.

http://www.carqueryapi.com

Note: they also provide data source download in xls or sql format at a premium price. but these data also provides technical specifications for all the make model and trim options.

Comment: I used car query for a while and honestly, it's plenty of errors. In a subset of 100 cars my customer tried there were a good percentage of them with wrong info, based on the free service. So I don't think it's a good idea to use it.

Comment: This api is very defensive. I tried to make several pages to provide user to navigate through: makes, models, trims. I fetched data on server side in order to make data visible to crawlers, but when Google crawled a site, api denied access because of great number of parallel queries. So my site cannot display data that way anymore.

Comment: This API might have been free to use when this answer was posted but it is not anymore. Hence this answer is no longer valid

Comment: Be sure to note that most of those used on automotive sites and even Amazon and eBay motors have some serious errors. For example, they list Imperial as a model of Chrysler when it was a separate make after 1954 and they list Clipper as a Packard when it was a separate make in 1956. I know it's knit-picking but these are legal terms.

Comment: I has been looking for similar car database and I came across this question and tried few websites including CarQueryAPI where I found numerous missing cars and errors so I had to ask for a refund. I was the happiest man when I found https://www.teoalida.com/cardatabase/ it does have many databases to choose from, some are cheap and some are really expensive but I contacted site owner via live chat and he prepared for me a custom list with only 2010-2019 models at lower price than what I would had to pay for full database 1990-2019. It worth my money, database being complete and very accurate.

Answer (score -6):

How about Freebase? I think they have an API available, too.

http://www.freebase.com/

Comment: The OP mentioned Freebase, and stated they had already rejected it as an option.

Comment: no longer available